# Discord.py - How to make a role specific command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I need to make a command that can only be executed by someone that has a certain role. I searched around on google and youtube to find a answer but came up with nothing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add a decorator on the command to restrict it to only members with specific roles or permissions. The documentation for it is [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.has_role). It would look like this:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_role('RoleName')
async def command_name():
```

Keep in mind that the `RoleName` string you pass is case sensitive.

Comment: I did this and now im getting a privilege too low error, though i have the role.. the spelling and capitals are the same

Comment: What is the command doing? Roles are hierarchical. A role can't modify a role that is higher in the hierarchy than itself. If the bot user tries to alter a person's nickname or kick a person when the target of the action has a higher role than the bot user, that error is given.