# How to check if a user has a specific role in on_message?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Currently I have a bot will give you a role if you do a command. I want to make the bot check if the user that does the command has a specific role. As of now I've only seen people do it with permissions. Basic examples would be also great!

```
if message.content.lower().startswith('/role'):
    user = message.author
    role = discord.utils.get(user.server.roles, id="437923291047526402")
    await client.add_roles(user, role)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Discord.py - How to make a role specific command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49351509/discord-py-how-to-make-a-role-specific-command)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check for roles in `on_message`, you can access the author's roles attribute.

```
if message.content.lower().startswith('/role'):
    user = message.author

    if message.channel.is_private or discord.utils.get(user.roles, name="admin") is None:
        return

    role = discord.utils.get(user.server.roles, id="437923291047526402")
    await client.add_roles(user, role)
```

For commands, see the linked dupe answer.