# Allowing users with a certain role access to a command

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

For some reason it wont allow me to make the command where certain users with a specific role called "DJ" access to a command. I have tried everything but still wont work.

```
@commands.command(pass_context=True, no_pm=True)
async def leave(self, ctx):
    if ctx.message.author.roles == 'DJ':
        try:
            server = ctx.message.server
            voice_client = self.client.voice_client_in(server)
            await voice_client.disconnect()
        except Exception as error:
            await self.client.say('{}'.format(error))
    else:
        await self.client.say('You require the role `DJ` to use this command.')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Discord.py - How to make a role specific command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49351509/discord-py-how-to-make-a-role-specific-command)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`author.roles` returns a list of `Role` objects so you have to iterate through that list and find one with a name "DJ"

You can do something like this

```
if "DJ" in [role.name.upper() for role in ctx.message.author.roles]:
```