# How to have discord.py bot have someone add and remove role of someone else

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I have a few roles in my discord like "Owner","Member" and "Jail". I want the bot to only be accessible by the "Owner" role and want the command to be something like this: .jail @user. Then the bot should take away the "Member" role and give them the "Jail" Role.

Discord Server latest update
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DA9Vx.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Discord.py - How to make a role specific command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49351509/discord-py-how-to-make-a-role-specific-command)

Answer (score 2):

For making commands only accessible by a specific role do something like this:

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_role("Name")
async def example(ctx):
 await ctx.send("This was an example for R.Peter!")
```

And for adding / taking away roles do something like this:

```py
@bot.command()
async def jail(ctx, member:discord.Member)
 jailrole=get(guild.roles, name="Jail")

 await member.add_roles(jailrole)
```

Taking away a role is the same except `await member.add_roles(jailrole)` becomes 
`await member.remove_roles(jailrole)`

Hopefully this answers your question!

Sources:

`@commands.has_role("Name")` [discord.py Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20has#discord.ext.commands.has_role)

`await member.add_roles(jailrole)` [discord.py Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member%20add#discord.Member.add_roles)

`await member.remove_roles` [discord.py Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member%20remove#discord.Member.remove_roles)

Comment: How do I set a command for the bot such as .Jail Also I keep getting a syntax error 
Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the question.. Could you post the error?